# Dynamic JAXB XML Deserialization (Unmarshalling)

Tags: xml, jaxb, deserialization

I want to deserialize (unmarshal) simple POJOs directly from an XML string, without any configuration (schema definition or other) file.

My application uses a simple base abstract class `Field` as follows:

```
public abstract class Field
{
    private final String name;
    private final Object value;

    protected Field(String name, Object value)
    {
        this.name  = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

which is extended by various other classes, such as

```
public class StringField extends Field
{
    public StringField(String name, String value)
    {
        super(name, value);
    }
}
```

Note that there is no no-arg constructor on any of these classes.

A serialized StringField POJO will look something like

```
<StringField>
    <name>test</name><type />
    <value>Some text</value>
</StringField>
```

Assuming that the above XML is stored in a String variable called `xml`, I am trying to use JAXB to deserialize, via the following method:

```
public static Field deserialize(String xml)
{
    Field field = null;

    try
    {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Field.class);

        javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();

        field = (Field)um.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
    }
    catch (JAXBException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return field;
}
```

Ideally, I would like to have the XML string deserialized into the appropriate Java POJO (i.e., StringField in the above case).

However, I am getting JAXB exceptions because Field does not have a no-arg constructor and, even if I put one there, because it cannot be instantiated.

But even if I make the Field class non-abstract, the values assigned via the default constructor to the 2 fields (name, value) are the ones prevailing, as opposed to the actual values deserialized from the XML string. Even if that worked, I would not get a child object (StringField) but a parent one (Field).

Is there any generic way of dynamically deserializing POJOs, without schema declarations, and getting actual (child) objects using JAXB?

Answer (score 4):

You need to annotate your fields

https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.6/docs/ch03.html#annotating-your-classes

With things like: @XmlElement and @XmlAttribute

Here is a good tutorial:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/JAXB/article.html

Hope that helps.